# Invariance of law of conservation of angular momentum under a Galilean transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, galilean-relativity

Given a reference frame O' moving at a constant speed $\vec{V}$ in relation to another reference frame O, I want to prove that

$\vec{r_{1B}} \times m_1\vec{v_{1B}} + \vec{r_{2B}} \times m_2\vec{v_{2B}} = \vec{r_{1F}} \times m_1\vec{v_{1F}} + \vec{r_{2F}} \times m_2\vec{v_{2F}}$

in O is equal to

$\vec{r'_{1B}} \times m_1\vec{v'_{1B}} + \vec{r'_{2B}} \times m_2\vec{v'_{2B}} = \vec{r'_{1F}} \times m_1\vec{v'_{1F}} + \vec{r'_{2F}} \times m_2\vec{v'_{2F}}$

in O'. The particles 1 and 2 are colliding (elastic collision). B stands for before the collision and F, after the collision.

Galilean transformation gives :

$\vec{r} = \vec{r'} + \vec{V}t$ and $\vec{v} = \vec{v'} + \vec{V}$

Substituting these expressions into the first equation and developing the cross products, I obtain, after having cancelled out 8 terms (because of the conservation of linear momentum),

$\vec{r'_{1B}} \times m_1\vec{v'_{1B}} + \vec{r'_{1B}} \times m_1\vec{V} + \vec{r'_{2B}} \times m_2\vec{v'_{2B}} + \vec{r'_{2B}} \times m_2\vec{V} = \vec{r'_{1F}} \times m_1\vec{v'_{1F}} + \vec{r'_{1F}} \times m_1\vec{V} + \vec{r'_{2F}} \times m_2\vec{v'_{2F}} + \vec{r'_{2F}} \times m_2\vec{V}$

My problem is that I do not know how to cancel out the $\vec{r'_{1B}} \times m_1\vec{V}$ terms... How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that angular momentum is conserved in all frames, but the actual value of the angular momentum will, in general be different.

If you look at the extra terms you will find that they correspond to the change in the angular momentum of the centre of mass about your chosen origin. 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}_{CM}\times M\mathbf{V} & = \frac{1}{M}(m_1\mathbf{r}_1 + m_2 \mathbf{r_2}) \times M\mathbf{V}\\
& = \mathbf{r}_1 \times m_1 \mathbf{V} + \mathbf{r}_2 \times m_2 \mathbf{V}
\end{align}